# Laravel/Eloquent - Query - Select with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

**Models**

```
class Model1 extends Eloquent {
    public function model2() {
        return $this->hasOne('Model2');
    }
}

class Model2 extends Eloquent {
    public function model1() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model1');
    }
}
```

**Query I want**

I want to get all instances from `Model1` which do **not** have a `Model2`. In other words, there isn't any reference to that `Model1` `id` in `Model2` table column `model1_id`.

This could be achieved with a `foreach` loop, iterating all the `Model1` and checking if the `model2` atributte is **null**. But I want to do it with Eloquent queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try something like

```
Model1::has('model2', '=', 0)->get();
```

See: [Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)

Update:

```
Model1::doesntHave('model2')->get();
```

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha its a sneaky one :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be it:

```
$ids = Model2::where('model1_id', null)->lists('id');
$result = Model1::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

edit:
I need to learn to read better :) I see that this is not it.

edit2:
This might be it. I havent tested it, but if there is an error then it should be easy to fix it! (With the help of lagbox on IRC channel #laravel)

edit3:
Okey, so after discussing it on #laravel with lagbox there is a even better way... see his answer